# Is there a recommended self-study syllabus or set of books for UAV design?

Tags: aircraft-design, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I'm junior software engineer (C/C++/Assembly) in a UAV project. After working there for some months I decided that it would be very interesting to start my own project. So, my goal is to design my own UAV from scratch at home. The main problem is lack of knowledge: I don't know anything about aerodynamics, engines, mechanics and so on...

It's not a problem for me to find materials on the web. The difficulty is that I don't know which disciplines to take and in which order. I understand that you should be good at calculus, differential equations, solid mechanics, aerodynamics and so on.

**So, the main question is**: which books/resources would you recommend and in which order?

P.S. I have found some stuff on [MIT OpenCourseWare](https://ocw.mit.edu/index.htm) but the information there is old and not complete. Books are much better. For example I found [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691149216) very helpful, but rather complicated.

**Update:** I decided to extend my question. So, let's try to structure all themes, that are needed.

Base:

- Math.
- Mechanics.
- Dynamics/Kinematics
- Aerodynamics.

Specific:

- Engines.
- Automatic Systems.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68759/discussion-on-question-by-le0nx-the-path-of-self-study-in-uav-design).